# HeapSetInformation error using c# and unmanaged DLL

Tags: c#, c++, winapi, dll

I'm making a wrapper from c# and a unmanaged DLL, all is working correctly except when I call a function that inside uses HeapSetInformation. HeapSetInformation every time returns 0. The same function called inside a visual C++ application is working correctly. For some reason inside C# is not possible to initialize the LFH. The unmanaged dll can't be modified and I don't have the source code. Someone has any idea how to resolve the problem? The test environment is Windows 7 x64 and Visual studio 2013 Framework 4.5

Best regards
GMG

Comment: Remove the call? - Vista onwards uses LFH [automatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366750%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), removing the need for you to do anything.  As an aside, it sets `GetLastError()` and wont work if a debugger is attached,

Comment: I can't modify the DLL as I write earlier, and HeapSetInformation  is called inside a DLL function that I must call. I have the same error also if I run the application in release without debugger.

Comment: Calling HeapSetInformation() from a DLL is a pretty criminal thing to do, a DLL should *never* monkey with such a global setting that affects all of the code in the process.  Unless it created the heap itself, in which case your C# code can't do anything to mess that up.  You have at least 2 good reasons to not use that DLL, I doubt we can do anything to subtract from that.  Try adding _NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1 to your environment.  Contact the owner for help.

Comment: As write before the DLL is not mine and I don't have control over it and I'm not here to discuss if is right or not to use HeapSetInformation inside it, I'm here only to ask if someone has a solution. So -1 is becuse I asck for help ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way out of this bind. The DLL is wrong to call `HeapSetInformation`.

The best solution would be to get the DLL fixed, or to stop using the DLL. If that is not possible then you could install a code hook on `HeapSetInformation` and arrange for it to do nothing, and return `TRUE`.